# How many ways are there to describe the Fibonacci sequence in Perl 6?

Tags: perl, lazy-evaluation, fibonacci, raku

I've been looking at the various ways of constructing lazy lists in Perl 6 and I would like to collect all of the concise ways of describing the Fibonacci sequence.

I will start this off with the three from [masak](http://use.perl.org/~masak/journal/)'s journal:

```
my @fibs := (0, 1, -> $a, $b { $a + $b } ... *);

my @fibs := (0, 1, { $^a + $^b } ... *);  

my @fibs := (0, 1, *+* ... *);
```

I was thinking something like this would also work, but I think I have the syntax wrong:

```
my @fibs := (0, 1, (@fibs Z+ @fibs[1..*]));
```

Something there is eager (the slice?) and causes Rakudo to enter an infinite loop.  It's a translation of the Haskell definition:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Update:

Seems like the problem with the `zipWith` example is the `@fibs[1..*]` slice.  if `tail` is defined as `sub tail (@x) {my $i = 1; {@x[$i++]}...*}` then it works properly.  I would be interested to know why the slice isn't lazy from anyone familiar with Rakudo's internals.

Another nice one is:

```
my @fibs := (0, [\+] 1, @fibs);
```

Comment: This is one of the reasons I like Perl 6. :)

Comment: Is the question about your bug, or about possible other solutions?  Your code is missing a closing parenthesis, if Perl 6's syntax isn't stranger than I thought...

Comment: Have you tried your code on Pugs?

Comment: @Charles => Thanks for catching the paren, fixed.  That was just a typo when I wrote the question.  I would like to collect all of the different ways to write the sequence.  I posted the zipWith solution as one that I think should be doable, but that I have not had success with.  I have not tried to run these in Pugs.

Answer (score 4):

The shortest seems to be

```
my @fibs := ^2,*+*...*;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the magic of the golden ratio: let φ=(sqrt(5)+1)/2, and define *fib(n)*=(φ<sup>n</sup>+(1-φ)<sup>n</sup>)/sqrt(5).

You can convert such a function into a lazy list in the obvious way: In Haskell the following works:

```
fibs=genfibs 0 where genfibs n=(round (fib n)):genfibs (n+1)
```

I'm afraid my Perl 6 knowledge isn't up to translating this, sorry!  Anyone who edits this answer to edit in the codes will earn my gratitude.

A more testing question would be to list ways of generating the lazy list of Hamming numbers.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but for clarification: the golder ratio is 0.5*(sqrt(5)+1) and the closed form of a fibonacci number is ((1+sqrt(5))^n - (1-sqrt(5))^n)/(2^n * sqrt(5)) = (φ^n-(1-φ)^n)/sqrt(5) [http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciNumber.html]

Comment: @Phil: Yes, I should have checked, at least that case n=0 worked. Far from a pedantic correction; many thanks.

Comment: A way to turn such a function to a lazy list in Perl 6 is `my @fibs = ->{ fib $++ } ... *`. I don't think what you have can be easily translated directly to Perl 6 as functions are not normally lazy. `$ perl6 -e 'constant φ = (sqrt(5)+1)/2; sub fib (\n) { (φ**n - (1-φ)**n)/sqrt(5) }; my @fibs = ->{ round fib $++ } ... *; say @fibs'`, although that starts getting incorrect results after the first 70 results because of floating point errors. ( I have gotten more correct numbers with FatRats, but that slows the calculations down considerably )