# Multiplication with Perl 6 Sequence Whatever (...) operator

Tags: perl, raku

I have seen examples of the Perl 6 whatever (...) operator in sequences, and I have tried to find out how to do a sequence which involves multiplications.

The operator does the following, if one starts with some numbers, one can specify a sequence of the numbers following it.

```
@natural = 1,2 ... *;
@powersOfTwo = 1,2,4 ... *;
```

and so on.
One could also define a sequence using the previous numbers in the sequence as in the fibonacci numbers (shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980842/)), where one does the following:

```
@fibonacci = 1,1, *+* ... *;
```

The problem is that the multiplication operator is `*` and the previous numbers are also represented with `*`.

While I can define a sequence using `+`, `-` and `/`, I can not seem to find a way of defining a sequence using `*`.

I have tried the following:

```
@powers = 1,2, *** ... *;
```

but it obviously does not work.

Does anyone know how to this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For one thing, Perl 6 is sensitive to whitespace.

```
1, 2, * * * ... *
```

is perfectly legitimate and generates a sequence that's sort of like a multiplicative fibonacci; it's just a little bit hard to read. `***` and `* * *` mean something different.

If the ambiguity bothers you, you can use an explicit block instead of the implicit one that using "whatever star" gives you:

```
1, 2, -> $a, $b { $a * $b } ... *
```

and

```
1, 2, { $^a * $^b } ... *
```

both produce the same sequence as `1, 2, * * * ... *` does (tested in Rakudo).

Answer (score 2):

```
my @powers_of_two := { 1, 2, { $^a * 2 } ... *);

my $n = 6;
my @powers_of_six := { 1, $n, { $^a * $n } ... *);
```